# ASP.NET 4.0 URL routing with two or multiple querystring parameters

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, asp.net-4.0

How can I pass two querysting parameters in URL routing using ASP.NET 4.0?

I have gone through many articles, but everywhere it shows only one parameter.

I'd like the display URL to be:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/reports/1-this-is-my-first-report
```

The first parameter is **ID**: `1`
The second is **Name**: `This is my first report`

I am trying following route, but it is not working

```
    routes.MapPageRoute(
       "MarketReports",               // Route name
       "Reports/{*i}-{*n}",  // Route URL
       "~/pageControl2.aspx"      // Web page to handle route
    );
```

How can I make this work as described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try formatting the URL this way:

http://www.mywebsite.com/reports/1/this-is-my-first-report

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
       "MarketReports",               // Route name
       "Reports/{*i}/{*n}",  // Route URL
       "~/pageControl2.aspx"      // Web page to handle route
    );
```

Comment: Thanks Brian,
It is working now.
but i have one more problem with routing & javascript
i am populating javascript menu.
It populates wrong reference.
How can i generate Rout URL for javascript Menu?

Comment: Try: var route = '<%$RouteUrl:locale=CA,year=2009,routename=salesroute%>';

Comment: Or try: var r = '<%= RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(Nothing, "ExpensesRoute", parameters) %>'; which would require an <%@ import statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Response.RedirectToRoute("UrlRouting for Querystring", 
    new { name = txtsearchurlrouting.Text,  text = txtsearchid.Text });
```

In Global.asax

```
routes.MapPageRoute("UrlRouting for Querystring", 
     "Querystring/Selected/{name}/{text}/", "~/Address.aspx");
```

like this we can pass multiple querystring parameters